# How to do last five pages visited usercontrol in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

Dim i As Integer = 0
        Dim productcount As Integer = 0

```
    If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("xxx") Is Nothing Then
        Dim gingernuts As New HttpCookie("xxx")
        gingernuts.Values("productcount") = 0
        gingernuts.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(365)
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(gingernuts)
    End If

    productcount = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("xxx")("productcount")

    For i = 0 To productcount
        If HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("xxx")("product" & i & "") = "" Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("xxx")("product" & i & "") = Request.QueryString("id")
        Else
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("xxx")("product" & i & "") = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies("xxx")("product" & i & "")
        End If
    Next

    If productcount = 5 Then
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("xxx")("productcount") = 5
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("xxx")("product0") = ""
    Else
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies("xxx")("productcount") = productcount + 1
    End If
```

I find this here but vb.net.how to do in asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

In this case I suggest you to use `Local Storage` instead of `cookies`. It's much simplier to use.

[Here](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) you have some information how to use it. On client site you can manage them and set/get as you want.